# What questions should be asked on which StackOverflow sister sites?

Tags: support

What questions should be asked on which StackOverflow sister sites?

Comment: I'd be especially curious about web programming questions, as those seem to be a grey area. This one for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1342103/what-unicode-character-do-you-use-in-your-website-instead-of-image-icons/1342217#1342217

Comment: @Mark: That isn't about web programming, that is about characters.

Comment: It's the kind of question a web programmer might need to know though, which maybe makes it a darker grey?

Answer (score 2):

Look at the bottom of the page:

- stackoverflow.com
- http://serverfault.com - Servers and workstations
- http://superuser.com - anything computer related
- http://meta.stackoverflow.com - discussion about Stackoverflow (like this question! :)
- http://howtogeek.com
- http://doctype.com - web design

Answer (score 1):

From the [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq):

> If your question is about …
>
> networking, servers, or maintaining
> other people's PCs and contains no
> source code, ask on [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com).
>
> general computer software or hardware
> troubleshooting, ask on [Super User](http://superuser.com).
>
> web design and HTML/CSS layout, and
> your job title is "designer", ask on
> [Doctype](http://doctype.com).

Answer (score 1):

This [google spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1uzPJgYMKuLVxrT5tKm6mPNajd2ai6_i8STkje2oD2D0/edit?usp=sharing) may help decide which site is appropriate.  It is a list of the top 10,000 tags across the top 100 sites in the stack exchange network.  It queries the stack exchange REST API to get a list of sites (returning the first 100), then generates another sheet to grab the top 100 tags from each site.  The final sheet (TagsSorted) then sorts them by popularity across all the sites.

NB: it may take a while to open ;)

I used [this ImportJSON google apps script](https://gist.github.com/paulgambill/cacd19da95a1421d3164) to query the REST API.

Answer (score 0):

Thought I would add [the most extensive list of Stack Exchange sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4/list-of-stackexchange-sites).