# How to decide on which site to ask a question (deciding between stackoverflow, superuser and unix & linux)

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I'd like to ask a question, whether it's possible to create patches using `git format-patch` against a remote git repository (i.e. not from a local clone/checkout).

As this is not necessarily about programming itself and does not require knowledge of a programming language, it doesn't fit that well at [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), but might still be interesting and valuable for programmers. But then, should it be asked better at [superuser](https://superuser.com/tour) or on [unix & linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/tour) and is there some way to distinguish between those three sites in general for new questions?

Took a look at the respective tour pages, and for some more generic question I have to admit there is some slight overlap, especially between superuser and unix stackexchange.

Took a look at [some](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/254498/where-can-i-find-rules-on-which-stack-exchange-community-site-my-question-should) [previous](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18131/what-questions-should-be-asked-on-which-stackoverflow-sister-sites) [questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/132659/super-user-versus-unix-and-linux-versus-ask-ubuntu) on this topic but didn't quite help on this matter.

Comment: The answers given there are pretty generic and don't actually answer my question, on how to decide between superuser and unix & linux ... Also it mainly adresses the difference between stackoverflow and other CS-related sites, which is not the topic of my particular question.
In my humble opinion this is not a duplicate of that existing question.

Comment: Yeah these aren't duplicates

Comment: The OP hasn't been here since August of last year. Based on # of usages the tag **git** stacks up like this: https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/git  https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/git  https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/git  https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/git - certainly the first has the most tags (2K) but [few questions](https://superuser.com/search?q=git+format-patch+is%3Aquestion) that are similar. With 120K questions on SO using the tag and [220 related Q&As](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22git+format-patch%22&mixed=0) it's not a *bad* place.

Comment: @Rob I've not been here because there's been no reply nor any helpful comment. What you are suggesting is to search for any specific tag over all sites, and then decide by the number of results where to post? That might be statistically correct, but it's not really helpful or feasible in my opinion.

Comment: doktor5000: "`decide by the number of results where to post? That might be statistically correct ...`", that's not what was suggested and were you looking for another description for "statistically correct"; such as [forecasting](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/33915/86889). The "[**here**](https://stackexchange.com/users/4996075/doktor5000?tab=activity)" referred to in *my* comment was any of our sites, not just this one. If you looked around you might have seen the question: "[How can I get answers fast?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8010/282094). Writing your own answer is encouraged.